# Whom to contact for opting out of a Visa Interview for USA?

Tags: visas, usa, embassies

Me and my family were planning for a Trip to USA / Canada this year... So all the travel documents including documents required for the USA Visa were collected and uploaded to the website. My brother is handing all this, and we've had to delay the Visa Interview Appointment once in May this year…

Now I've been travelling within India a lot this year… and have to travel again in July. My dad's not been feeling alright lately, so we've decided to plan this tour for next year… or only my brother and his wife will be going, we'll stay back this year.

I'm planning to travel somewhere again within India next month, but the visa interview appointment is making me wait until post-15th July. I asked my brother why this interview cannot be delayed, he said money will be charged if we delay the interview again. Previously also I had requested a delay, and he replied the same thing. And still it was delayed, due to my father's health. I'm trying to convince him to delay the interview until October this year, but he's keen on getting the visa before that.

My question is: If only my brother and his wife are going to the USA, is it necessary for me to apply for a visa too? I'm an Indian resident, and maybe they ask questions like "Whole Family WAS going? Why now only you two are going?" due to which, I'm being told, the visa can be denied. 
Also, Can I opt of out this Interview? I don't want the visa this year… It'll be raining there in USA until October, after which it'll be snowing… I was thinking of writing a opt out email to the embassy, but guess that's not a good idea.

Could anyone suggest of what I could do to avoid wasting my time for an interview which for sure is again going to be delayed. I'm only asking if I can opt out, without interfering with my brother's visa approval.

Comment: Not really following you here.  So you have decided not to go?  Then just cancel your interview.  End of story.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is anything at all suspicious about "my father is sick and my brother [you] is staying behind to take care of him".  I'd almost say the opposite: since strong family ties are evidence that you're *not* going to immigrate, this should be in your brother's favor!

Comment: Hi @jpatokal! Your second comment is a relief... Hopefully I'll get myself opted out next week... Thanks! :)

Comment: @mk117 jpatokal's right! Cancel your interview and even if they question your brother regarding it, there would be no issues. Change of plans is quite normal and someone "not" accompanying should not affect the application of someone unless they are dependents in any form.

Comment: @jpatokal you could potentially turn that into an answer.

Comment: @jpatokal have tempted you with a bounty ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have decided not to go, then just **cancel your interview**.  End of story.  It's not going to reflect badly on you or your family, and it's certainly better than being denied a visa.

Also, I don't think there is anything at all suspicious about "my father is sick and my brother [you] is staying behind to take care of him". I'd almost say the opposite: since strong family ties are evidence that you're not going to immigrate, this should be in your brother's favor!

Comment: Well, this question is more than 6 months old, and I already got the visa in July! Thanks anyways! :)